# Add multiples images to Edit Text View Android

Tags: android, image, android-edittext

I have 2 images one is "(" and another ")"  how I can add these to EditTextView backgroud and stretch them the size of the EditTextView changes .

I tried to use layer_list without any luck .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put those into `<ImageView>`s and put one to the left and one to the right of the `EditText`. Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
      <ImageView
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edit_text"/>
      <EditText android:id="@id/edit_text"/>
      <ImageView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edit_text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course you will need to add more attributes to the above, but it is a template for you to get started.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/left_bracket"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/right bracket".
```

**N.B.**

> - by using android:drawableLeft the drawtable to be drawn to the left    of the text.
> - by using android:drawableRigh the drawable to be drawn to the right    of the text.

Comment: @Rod. you are welcome..welcome to the community.. if you think my answer was helpful you can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark at the left side... or can upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="120dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:hint="@string/search_titles"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_bar_end_right_inactive"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_bar_end_left_inactive"
  </EditText>
```

How I can stretch the images when the textfield is re sizing .?